# Javascript filter and sort value

Tags: javascript, sorting, filter

I'm trying to filter and sort my data. which is matched all value in the array it will be at the first of array.

```
const fruits = [
  {name: 'banana', vitamins: ['Vitamin_C2', 'Vitamin_B']},
  {name: 'orange', vitamins: ['Vitamin_B', 'Vitamin_A1', 'Vitamin_D']},
  {name: 'apple', vitamins: ['Vitamin_C2', 'Vitamin_C', 'Vitamin_B']},
]

const vitaminsArray = ['Vitamin_C2', 'Vitamin_C', 'Vitamin_B'];

function filterAndSort(vitaminsArray) {
 // enter amazing code here :P
}

// console.log(filterAndSort) expect output. it will filter vitamins object and sort the most on the first of the object.
[
 {name: 'apple', vitamins: ['Vitamin_C2', 'Vitamin_C', 'Vitamin_B']},
 {name: 'banana', vitamins: ['Vitamin_C2', 'Vitamin_B']},
 {name: 'orange', vitamins: ['Vitamin_B', 'Vitamin_A1', 'Vitamin_D']},
]
```

I tried it filter but I cannot do the sort. This is my code.

```
const filtered = fruits.filter(fruit => {
  return vitaminsArray.some((type) => fruit.vitamins.includes(type));
})
  // output 
   [
     {name: 'banana', vitamins: ['Vitamin_C2', 'Vitamin_B']},
     {name: 'apple', vitamins: ['Vitamin_C2', 'Vitamin_C', 'Vitamin_B']},
     {name: 'orange', vitamins: ['Vitamin_B', 'Vitamin_A1', 'Vitamin_D']},
   ]
```

Comment: ops. sorry i typo. thanks for bring up it!

Comment: You didn't called the sort function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort by the length of the [intersection of the arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript) `vitaminsArray` and `vitamins`. The longest result means the current object has the most items from `vitaminsArray`

```js
const fruits = [
  {name: 'banana', vitamins: ['Vitamin_C2', 'Vitamin_B']},
  {name: 'orange', vitamins: ['Vitamin_B', 'Vitamin_A1', 'Vitamin_D']},
  {name: 'apple', vitamins: ['Vitamin_C2', 'Vitamin_C', 'Vitamin_B']},
];

const vitaminsArray = ['Vitamin_C2', 'Vitamin_C', 'Vitamin_B'];

const filtered = fruits.filter(fruit => {
  return vitaminsArray.some((type) => fruit.vitamins.includes(type));
});

console.log("before sorting");
console.log(filtered);

const sorted = filtered.sort((a, b) => {
    return vitaminsArray.filter(value => b.vitamins.includes(value)).length - vitaminsArray.filter(value => a.vitamins.includes(value)).length;
})

console.log("after sorting");
console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following,

```js
const fruits = [
  {name: 'banana', vitamins: ['Vitamin_C2', 'Vitamin_B']},
  {name: 'orange', vitamins: ['Vitamin_B', 'Vitamin_A1', 'Vitamin_D']},
  {name: 'apple', vitamins: ['Vitamin_C2', 'Vitamin_C', 'Vitamin_B']},
]

const vitaminsArray = ['Vitamin_C2', 'Vitamin_C', 'Vitamin_B'];

function filterAndSort() {
 return fruits.sort((a,b) => {
     a.vitamins = a.vitamins.filter(item => vitaminsArray.includes(item));
     b.vitamins = b.vitamins.filter(item => vitaminsArray.includes(item));
     let aMatch = a.vitamins.length;
     let bMatch = b.vitamins.length;
     return bMatch - aMatch;
 });
}


console.log(filterAndSort());
// console.log(filterAndSort) expect output. it will filter vitamins object and sort the most on the first of object.
/* [
 {name: 'apple', vitamins: ['Vitamin_C2', 'Vitamin_C', 'Vitamin_B']},
 {name: 'banana', vitamins: ['Vitamin_C2', 'Vitamin_B']},
]*/
```

Comment: Thank you fror you time to share code and solved my issue =)

Comment: Updated the code to filter the vitamins as well.